# What is the difference between "source script.sh" and "./script.sh"?

Tags: linux, shell, unix

What is the difference between `source <script>` and `./<script>`?

Comment: Also, then, what is the difference between those two and `sh <script>`? I'm guessing its more like `./<script>`

Answer (score 51, accepted):

`source script.sh` runs the script within the current process, thus all variable assignments are preserved as variables even after the script finishes (and don't have to be explicitly `export`'d).

`./script.sh` just runs the script in a subprocess, and any variables which are assigned disappear after the script is done.

Comment: Note that `./script.sh` can only export variables to children, not back to the parent.

Comment: Not all variables are environment variables; they only become environment variables when they're `export`ed. Both ordinary shell variables and environment variables can be updated by `source script.sh` (or `. script.sh`).

Answer (score 6):

source script will change your current environment, ./script will not.

(EDIT: script has to be executable to use ./)