# add a alias to machine via a script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

we are using cloud 9 ide for a dev machines. with in our git repo we have a setup script that configures certain env variables, sets up mysql etc. as part of this I want to add a alias

```
alias pu='vendor/bin/phpunit tests/'
```

when I run this on the command line it does what I expect and I can use the command pu

but when i run it as part of a script is does not add it and I cannot use the command pu

is there something I need to do first?

Comment: tried to source the script?

Comment: I don't know what that means, do you mean like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779756/what-is-the-difference-between-source-script-sh-and-script-sh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should nut execute the script, because it will be run in another shell. You need to use the `source` or `.` command, which will execute the commands that your script contains in the *current* shell. (see `man bash` for details)

For example, you could add a line like this:

```
if [[ -f 'your_file_name.bash' ]]; then
    source your_file_name.bash
fi
```

to your `~/.bashrc`. The above code first checks for the existence of your file, then sources it to the current shell.