# How to source the output of a command in a shell script?

Tags: linux, shell

I got `export.sh` which includes the following command:

```
#!/bin/bash
$(aws-env prod)
```

The output of `aws-env prod` is:

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=xxxxxxx
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=xxxxxxxx
```

I would like to run that output(export the env variables) once I run `./export.sh`

I don't know what I'm missing because if I run the command `$(aws-env prod)` directly in the terminal, it does its work and export the env variables, but it's not doing in the shell script.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between "source script.sh" and "./script.sh"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779756/what-is-the-difference-between-source-script-sh-and-script-sh)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to source it to be able to set variables in current shell:

```
source export.sh
```

Otherwise by running `./export.sh` variables are set in a child subshell only.