# How to run Bash 'export' command from a file in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, file, variables, export

I am surprised that I am able to run other commands except the export command from an executable file in Linux.

```
    [root@test test1]# cat test

    export test="1"
    [root@test test1]# ./test
    [root@test test1]# env | grep test
    [root@test test1]# env | grep TEST

    [root@test test1]# export test=2
    [root@test test1]# env | grep test
    test=2
```

The 'test' file has a variable named test. However, after running the file, the 'test' variable is not present in my environment variables. If I simply run the command in Bash, the variable is shown.

Comment: You need to `source test` to be able to see the variables created inside that script.  See: [What is the difference between “source script.sh” and “./script.sh”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4779756/6862601)

Comment: Then I get the "-bash: source: /usr/bin/test: cannot execute binary file" error.

Comment: You have to do `source ./test`; `test` is not a good name for your file as it's both a built-in and an executable.

Comment: Thanks for the link, that makes sense.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between "source script.sh" and "./script.sh"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779756/what-is-the-difference-between-source-script-sh-and-script-sh)

Comment: I don't think that's an exact duplicate. It's more a problem of `. filename` vs `. ./filename`.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I had to do the following to fix;

```
source ./test
```

Or you can convert the file to a ".txt" extension and then use

```
source test.txt
```

to export the variable.

Comment: The extension wasn't the problem, not using `./` was. If you don't, the `$PATH` is searched for `test`, and it's found as an executable at `/bin/test`. The current directory usually isn't (and for security reasons shouldn't be) in the `$PATH`.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems here.

1. A script cannot modify the environment of its parent process.

   `./test` will run a subshell, and in that subshell, `export` the variable.  The subshell then exits, and the environment in which the variable was exported ceases to exist along with all the other resources the subshell used.

   This is a common FAQ; [Global environment variables in a shell script](/questions/1464253/global-environment-variables-in-a-shell-script)
2. The superficial fix for that is to `source ./test` but without the `./` you end up with Bash examining the `PATH` and finding `/bin/test`.  Rename your file to something which doesn't overlap with an existing command, use `source ./test` or `source /path/to/current/directory/test` instead of `source test` without a path; or (as absolutely the least recommended solution, but I'll still mention it for completeness) add `.` to the beginning of your `PATH` so that `./test` is preferred over `/bin/test` during `PATH` resolution.