# ubuntu function, works when sourced, but not with the bash command

Tags: bash

I'm trying to learn how to write some basic functions in Ubuntu, and I've found that some of them work, and some do not, and I can't figure out why.

Specifically, the following function `addseq2.sh` will work when I source it, but when I just try to run it with `bash addseq2.sh`it doesn't work. When I check with `$?` I get a `0: command not found`.  Does anyone have an idea why this might be the case? Thanks for any suggestions!

Here's the code for `addseq2.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# File: addseq2.sh

function addseq2 {
  local sum=0

  for element in $@
  do
    let sum=sum+$element
  done

  echo $sum
}
```

Thanks everyone for all the useful advice and help!

To expand on my original question, I have two simple functions already written.  The first one, `hello.sh` looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# File: hello.sh

function hello {
  echo "Hello"
}

hello
hello
hello
```

When I call this function, without having done anything else, I would type:

```
$ bash hello.sh
```

Which seems to work fine.  After I source it with `$ source hello.sh`, I'm then able to just type `hello` and it also runs as expected.

So what has been driving me crazy is the first function I mentioned here, `addseq2.sh`.  If I try to repeat the same steps, calling it just with `$ bash addseq2.sh 1 2 3`. I don't see any result.  I can see after checking as you suggested with `$ echo $?`that I get a 0 and it executed correctly, but nothing prints to the screen.

After I source it with `$ source addseq2.sh`, then I call it just by typing `$ addseq2 1 2 3` it returns `6` as expected.

I don't understand why the two functions are behaving differently.

Comment: Show how to call the function and what the expected result is.

Comment: If you execute the script, it defines the function in a shell that immediately exits; the function is never defined in the shell from which you execute the script. That's why you need to use `source`.

Comment: See: [What is the difference between “source script.sh” and “./script.sh”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4779756/3776858)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `bash foo.sh`, it spawns a new instance of `bash`, which then reads and executes every command in `foo.sh`.

---

In the case of `hello.sh`, the commands are:

```
function hello {
  echo "Hello"
}
```

This command has no visible effects, but it defines a function named `hello`.

```
hello
hello
hello
```

These commands call the `hello` function three times, each printing `Hello` to stdout.

Upon reaching the end of the script, `bash` exits with a status of 0. The `hello` function is gone (it was only defined within the bash process that just stopped running).

---

In the case of `addseq2.sh`, the commands are:

```
function addseq2 {
  local sum=0

  for element in $@
  do
    let sum=sum+$element
  done

  echo $sum
}
```

This command has no visible effects, but it defines a function named `addseq2`.

Upon reaching the end of the script, `bash` exits with a status of 0. The `addseq2` function is gone (it was only defined within the bash process that just stopped running).

That's why `bash addseq2.sh` does nothing: It simply defines (and immediately forgets) a function without ever calling it.

---

The `source` command is different. It tells the currently running shell to execute commands from a file as if you had typed them on the command line. The commands themselves still execute as before, but now the functions persist because the `bash` process they were defined in is still alive.

If you want `bash addseq2.sh 1 2 3` to automatically call the `addseq2` function and pass it the list of command line arguments, you have to say so explicitly: Add

```
addseq2 "$@"
```

at the end of `addseq2.sh`.

Answer (score 0):

*When I check with $? I get a 0: command not found*

This is because of the way you are checking it, for example:
(the leading `$` is the convention for showing the command-line prompt)

```
$ $?
-bash: 0: command not found
```

Instead you could do this:

```
$ echo $?
0
```

By convention `0` indicated success.  A better way to test in a script is something like this:

```
if addseq.sh
then
    echo 'script worked'
else
    # Redirect error message to stderr
    echo 'script failed' >&2   
fi
```

Now, why might your script not "work" even though it returned `0`?  You have a function but you are not calling it.  With your code I appended a call:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# File: addseq2.sh

function addseq2 {
  local sum=0

  for element in $@
  do
    let sum=sum+$element
  done

  echo $sum
}

addseq2 1 2 3 4          # <<<<<<<
```

and I got:

```
10
```

By the way, an alternative way of saying:

```
let sum=sum+$element
```

is:

```
sum=$((sum + element))
```