# How do i permanently append to a PATH variable using a script on git-bash for windows?

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables, git-bash

I am using git-bash on windows to execute the following lines.
What i have seen is that the changes are not persistent or permanent once i
close the existing session and open a new git-bash shell window or session.
How can i make these changes to the PATH variable permanent on windows?

```
#!/bin/bash
#########Sample GitBash Shell Script on Windows############
echo "Append to PATH"
echo $PATH
PATH=$PATH:/c/temp
export PATH
echo $PATH
```

Comment: Do you want this change to the path to apply, even when you're doing something other than running `git-bash`?

Comment: If so, you could modify the path in the environmental variables in Windows itself.

Comment: @AnnL. Yes, i understand we can change the path in windows directly. But i want to be able to do the same using a script.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in a git bash session, and want your script to impact your current shell environment, you cannot execute the script (that would spawn a sub-shell)

You need to [*source* your script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4779778/6309):

```
cd /path/to/your/script
source yourScript.sh
```

Then `echo $PATH` would display the updated value.

Comment: I am not concerned about the current shell environment. I want the changes to be permanent outside of my shell environment. In other words, it should behave the same way when we edit the environment variables directly in windows.